# lambda expression accepts sentence from user

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, expression

I am writing a program that uses lambda expressions to accept a string a from user, convert it to all lowercase and remove punctuation, then it lists the unique words in alphabetical order. I am having trouble getting my program to accept a sentence from the user and also removing punctuation. I have tried using `.replaceAll()` but I get an error so I must not be doing it right or thats not the correct code to use. Any help is appreciated. Here the code I have so far:

```
//I added my own string just to see if the code I have works.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = {"The brown fox chased the white rabbit."};


    System.out.printf("Original strings: %s%n", Arrays.asList(strings));


    Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>> uniqueWords = Arrays.stream(strings)
         .map(String::toLowerCase)
         //remove punctuation?
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()))
         .entrySet().stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
         .distinct();
    System.out.println("Unique words in Alphabetical Order: "+ uniqueWords);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a `Scanner`?

Comment: I did try to use scanner but I messed up the array somehow when I prompted the user to enter text. It wasn't storing the string properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Scanner` to accept user input, using the `nextLine()` method to accept a line of input from the console. Then you can [`toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) to convert the sentence to lowercase, and then [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to create the `Array`. You can use the regular expression `\\W+`, which will split on any non word character.

Also you are over complicating the `Stream`. You only have to use [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) and [`sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) to create a stream of unique values in alphabetical order:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] strings = in.nextLine().toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
System.out.printf("Original strings: %s%n", Arrays.asList(strings));
Arrays.stream(strings).distinct().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

***Sample Input/Output:***

```
This This is. a sentence with duplicate words words, and punctuation!!
Original strings: [this, this, is, a, sentence, with, duplicate, words, words, and, punctuation]
a
and
duplicate
is
punctuation
sentence
this
with
words
```